# Mod_PageSpeed issue with EC2 and SilverStripe

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, silverstripe, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

Not a large amount of information online in regards to this setup.

So as far as I know Mod_PageSpeed is setup and working (kind of). 
I can access /pagespeed_admin and when I check the headers the PageSpeed version is displayed.

The issue I get when Mod_PageSpeed is running is any image that pagespeed tries to dish out can't be found.

For example:
http://www.example.com/assets/Uploads/Clients/_resampled/PadWyIzNTAiLCIzNTAiLCJGRkZGRkYiXQ/xms-logo.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Ais8y38Ol-.webp

The above will get a 403 Forbidden error message.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted a real link.

Its  seems all you would have to do is change the permissions of the images to public.